# How to move git project from AWS CodeCommit to BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to move a project repository from **AWS CodeCommit** to **BitBucket** by using

> `git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:******/********.git`

to change the repository and then push the code to **bitBucket** repository but **AWS CodeCommit** not allowing. Is there any other solution to move codes from AWS CodeCommit to BitBucket keeping all the previous commit records.

Comment: So, you created an empty repository on bitbucket, set up the new remote on your local repo, tried to push and it failed?

Comment: exactly like that..

Comment: What is the error message when you try to push to bitbucket?

Comment: Problem solved. 
first clone the repository from aws codecommit then open git bash from inside of the cloned folder and change remote origin as it is in the question and then push to exact branch. It asked for git credential for bitBucket once i put right credential the code pushed to bitBucket repository . thanks Edmundo for fast response thanks

Comment: I thought you already had the two remotes set up (you would have one called bb and another called aws, for example). Glad you already solved it.

Comment: @SovanJana Can you please answer your question and mark it?